# Why did the author prove that $f'(z) \neq 0$ on an open circle $D(0, \delta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am reading "Lectures on Complex Function Theory" by Takaaki Nomura.
There is the following theorem in this book:

> Let $f(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ be a power series whose radius of convergence is $\rho > 0$.
> Let $f'(0) \neq 0$.
> There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(z)$ is injective and $f'(z) \neq 0$ on the open circle $D(0, \delta)$.

Its proof is the following:

> Proof:
> Let $g(z) := \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n |a_n| z^{n-1}$.
> The radius of convergence of $g(z)$ is $\rho$.
> Since $g(0) = 0$ and $a_1 = f'(0) \neq 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta < \rho$ and $0 \leq g(\delta) < \frac{1}{2} |a_1|$.
> Let $|z| < \delta$ and $|w| < \delta$ and $z \neq w$.
> Then $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}=a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n (z^{n-1} + z^{n-2} w + \cdots + w^{n-1}).$
> So, $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}\geq |a_1|-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n |a_n| \delta^{n-1} = |a_1| - g(\delta) > \frac{1}{2} |a_1| > 0.$
> So, $f(z)$ is injective on the open circle $D(0,\delta)$.
> Since $\lim_{w \to z} |\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}| = |f'(z)| \geq \frac{1}{2} |a_1| > 0$, $f'(z)\neq 0$ on the open circle $D(0,\delta)$.

My question is here:
$f'(z)$ is differentiable inside the circle of convergence $D(0,\rho)$.
So, $f'(z)$ is continuous inside the circle of convergence $D(0,\rho)$.
Since $f'(0) \neq 0$ and $f'(z)$ is continuous at $z=0$, $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z) = f'(0) \neq 0$.
So, $f'(z)$ is not equal to $0$ near $z = 0$.
And this argument is very obvious for all of us.
So I think we don't need to prove that $f'(z) \neq 0$ on an open circle $D(0, \delta)$.

I think the author should write as the following:

> Proof:
> Let $g(z) := \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n |a_n| z^{n-1}$.
> The radius of convergence of $g(z)$ is $\rho$.
> Since $g(0) = 0$ and $a_1 = f'(0) \neq 0$, there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $\delta' < \rho$ and $0 \leq g(\delta') < \frac{1}{2} |a_1|$.
> Let $|z| < \delta'$ and $|w| < \delta'$ and $z \neq w$.
> Then $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}=a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n (z^{n-1} + z^{n-2} w + \cdots + w^{n-1}).$
> So, $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}\geq |a_1|-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n |a_n| (\delta')^{n-1} = |a_1| - g(\delta') > \frac{1}{2} |a_1| > 0.$
> So, $f(z)$ is injective on the open circle $D(0,\delta')$.
> And obviously there exists $\delta^{''} > 0$ such that $f'(z) \neq 0$ on the open circle $D(0,\delta^{''})$.
> Let $\delta := \min(\delta', \delta^{''})$.

Comment: You did not prove injectivity. $f'(z) \neq 0$ does not imply that $f$ is injective.

Comment: The main point was to prove injectivity of $f(z)$ in a neighbourhood.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think the author need to prove that $f$ is injective but the author don't need to prove that  $f'(z) \neq 0$ because it is obvious for us.

Comment: @Lelouch I know that. But the author proved the fact which all of us know. I don't like that.

Comment: It's true that the fact that $f'(z)\not=0$ in a neighborhood of $0$ is not very relevant here, it also doesn't require that $f$ is a power series, just that $f'$ is continuous. It can still be useful to state it for later purposes.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Thank you very much.